# Change 'References' dialog width?

Tags: vb6, ide

I want to give the Reference popup tool window a wider default width to show more information.  I've done this before on another machine but I don't know how. Is it a registry hack?

Thanks in advance because it's very annoying that this toolwindow can't be resized. It obscures certain information which cannot be viewed otherwise.

[image: Default]

[image: "Hacked"]

Comment: The only way I know to change these windows is with a [3rd party tool](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/03/02/redesign-ide-dialogs.aspx).

Comment: PERFECT, thanks very much Brian, the tool (Resource Hacker) works very well.

Comment: I read a tip years ago that you could edit and save the dialog in C++ if you had it installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool (Resource Hacker) works very well and not only for VB6  ;-).
Thanks Brian !
Question closed.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>(Since the other answer doesn't actually describe what to do - I've copied it here in case the external link goes dead).</sub>

---

A process to do this is described in the following article, excerpted here:

(from https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/03/02/redesign-ide-dialogs.aspx)

> **Redesign IDE Dialogs**
>
> *By Karl E. Peterson 03/02/2010*
>
> ...Well, there's a tool you can use to do modify these sorts of
>   settings to your heart's content. [**Resource Hacker**](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/) is a freeware
>   utility to view, modify, rename, add, delete and extract resources in
>   32-bit Windows executables and resource files.
>
> ResHacker offers a dialog tool that's extremely similar to Classic
>   VB's -- you just drag the dialog elements around, resizing them to
>   suit. Or you can edit the raw resource script, and watch the changes
>   play out in the dialog designer. Simply open the "Dialog" node in the
>   treeview, find the dialog you want to edit, and go to town. When
>   you're happy with the new design, press the "Compile Script" button,
>   then just do a File | Save to write the changes to disk. (Be sure to
>   make a backup of the original file, first...)
>
> To modify the Classic VB Project-References dialog, open the
>   `VB6IDE.DLL` (or `VB5IDE.DLL`) file in ResHacker, find Dialog #4040 and
>   get to work.

The article also included two resource scripts - the modified, wider version, and also the original as a reference / backup.

**Modified:**

```
4040 DIALOG 0, 0, 455, 305
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "References"
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
FONT 8, "Tahoma"
{
   CONTROL "&Available References:", -1, STATIC, SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 7, 7, 73, 8 
   CONTROL "", 5050, LISTBOX, LBS_NOTIFY | LBS_MULTIPLESEL | LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LBS_HASSTRINGS | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP, 7, 19, 382, 235 
   CONTROL "OK", 1, BUTTON, BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP, 398, 18, 50, 14 
   CONTROL "Cancel", 2, BUTTON, BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 398, 40, 50, 14 
   CONTROL "&Browse...", 5051, BUTTON, BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 398, 61, 50, 14 
   CONTROL "&Help", 5052, BUTTON, BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 398, 240, 50, 14 
   CONTROL "Result", 5055, BUTTON, BS_GROUPBOX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 8, 260, 442, 37 
   CONTROL "Location:", -1, STATIC, SS_LEFT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 14, 271, 32, 8 
   CONTROL "", 5053, STATIC, SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP | SS_NOPREFIX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 52, 271, 390, 8 
   CONTROL "Language:", -1, STATIC, SS_LEFT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 14, 282, 36, 8 
   CONTROL "", 5054, STATIC, SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP | SS_NOPREFIX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 52, 282, 390, 8 
   CONTROL "&U", 4528, BUTTON, BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP, 416, 122, 14, 14 
   CONTROL "&D", 4529, BUTTON, BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 416, 149, 14, 14 
   CONTROL "Priority", -1, STATIC, SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP | SS_NOPREFIX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 411, 139, 24, 8 
}
```

**Original:**

```
4040 DIALOG 0, 0, 295, 204
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "References"
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
FONT 8, "Tahoma"
{
   CONTROL "&Available References:", -1, STATIC, SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 7, 7, 73, 8 
   CONTROL "", 5050, LISTBOX, LBS_NOTIFY | LBS_MULTIPLESEL | LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LBS_HASSTRINGS | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP, 7, 24, 193, 123 
   CONTROL "OK", 1, BUTTON, BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP, 238, 6, 50, 14 
   CONTROL "Cancel", 2, BUTTON, BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 238, 23, 50, 14 
   CONTROL "&Browse...", 5051, BUTTON, BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 238, 45, 50, 14 
   CONTROL "&Help", 5052, BUTTON, BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 238, 84, 50, 14 
   CONTROL "Result", 5055, BUTTON, BS_GROUPBOX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 7, 154, 281, 43 
   CONTROL "Location:", -1, STATIC, SS_LEFT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 35, 168, 32, 8 
   CONTROL "", 5053, STATIC, SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP | SS_NOPREFIX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 75, 168, 198, 8 
   CONTROL "Language:", -1, STATIC, SS_LEFT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 35, 180, 36, 8 
   CONTROL "", 5054, STATIC, SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP | SS_NOPREFIX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 77, 180, 196, 8 
   CONTROL "&U", 4528, BUTTON, BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP, 211, 62, 14, 14 
   CONTROL "&D", 4529, BUTTON, BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 211, 96, 14, 14 
   CONTROL "Priority", -1, STATIC, SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP | SS_NOPREFIX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 206, 82, 24, 8 
}
```

I've just tried this and it worked correctly. (Using VB6 Enterprise Edition + SP6.)